# Convert August, 2018 t0 2018-08-01 in PHP

Tags: php, date

I've converted 2018-08-01 to August, 2018 using `date("F, Y", strtotime($target))`
How can i reverse this?

Comment: You cannot. You discarded information in the date (specifically the day of the month) that is critical to reversal.

Comment: Don't convert it / use the original value

Comment: Keep your date values as date values throughout the application, only "convert" them for display purposes.

Comment: `strtotime` will do it but it will set the day to month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you always want the first day of the month, you can prepend `1` and then call `strtotime()`.

```
$month = "August, 2018";
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("1 $month"));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) with [relative formats](https://www.php.net/manual/de/datetime.formats.relative.php) too:

```
$yearMonth = str_replace(',', '', "August, 2018");
print (new DateTime("First day of $yearMonth"))->format('Y-m-d');
```

Results in:

```
2018-08-01
```